# Tableau: A CNTD(Field) is only showing 1 instead of the count of rows within a column

Tags: visualization, tableau-api, dashboard, calculation

I apologize in advanced for not being able to share a file. I will try my best to explain via screenshots here.

In the "Resource by Project" view what you're seeing is the action filter result that drills down from the pie chart above.

As we can see currently selected is the Cardiovascular Specialty Solutions Segment in which are 11 projects. In order to get this 11 I applied a CNTD on the project ID's that are associated with each one of the projects in the list. The issue I'm having is that when I apply the same CNTD to the ID's and attach that as a detail within the "Resource by Project" title, I see the number 1. Thats it.. 1 whereas we can clearly see that there are 11 projects.

I went ahead and changed the CountD(ProjectId) to just Count(ProjectId) and now I'm seeing something I've never seen before.. # of projects : 1 to 7 .. I dont know where the 1 to 7 came from .. all I'm trying to see are my simple totals that should match the 11 that shows up within the pie chart.

Some notes:

As we can see in the screenshot, I tried moving project Detail distinct count onto the Details and that worked for the Pie but not for my details sheet.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

[Project Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXgrO.png)
[Project Count - Pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkAwd.png)

Comment: There are many project Ids... but you mentioned only one project id

Comment: Hi Srikanth, thank you but I'm not sure I understand your response. I'm counting all project ID's by distinct on the project Id field.